# How to Call a function from a timer

Tags: c#

I want to call a function after an interval in uwp so I have this:

```
 private void TimedEvent()
        {
           aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Interval = 40000;
           aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(PresencePage_Loaded);
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;

        }

 private async void PresencePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {}
```

However I get a no overload for presencePage_loaded matches delegate ElapsedeventHandler error.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elapsed is declared as

```
public event System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler Elapsed;
```

where as loaded is

```
public event System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler Loaded;
```

as the events have different types you can't use the handler for one as a handler for the other

the simplest option would be to pull your logic out of the handler into a function

```
public async Task DoSomething(){...}
```

then you can have 2 handlers that call this function ie

```
private async void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    await DoSomething();
}

private async void PresencePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await DoSomething();
}
```

which would be attached as follows

```
aTimer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
```

Answer (score 4):

The signature of the [`ElapsedEventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.elapsedeventhandler?view=net-5.0) delegate is:

```
public delegate void ElapsedEventHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e);
```

You need to change your method signature to match, so you need to change `RoutedEventArgs` to `ElapsedEventArgs`:

```
private async void PresencePage_Loaded(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: might cause more problems than it fixes as PresencePage_Loaded is the default for the loaded event so changing its signature will break the pages event